# Javascript confirm with link

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

```
 $insert = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO orders  
(OrderID,Ordered,date_adds) VALUES ('$no','$checkout',NOW())");


if ($insert_it){

echo '
 <script>alert ("awtsu")</script>
    <script>myFunction</script>
';


}



 <script>
function myFunction() {
var txt;
var r = confirm("Cliicq a button!");
if (r == true) {

  txt = window.open('confirm.php<?php echo "?order=$no"; ?> ','_self');
} else {
    txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
}

}
</script>
```

How to use confirm without using button onclick ? when the query is set the dialog yes or no is not working. what is the proper syntax ? when the $insert it is set I want to have an dialog box with two option, when clicked yes It will directly go to another link

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Why do you have PHP and SQL in something that seems like an issue with a `confirm()` ?

Comment: are you trying to do myFunction() with brackets?